# Using PDFTK, input pdf is not an acroform, how to make it an acroform

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, pdftk

I am using pdftk in my web app.. first I am merging 3 pdf templates with fillable forms into one pdf template with fillable forms (let's call it 'simple.pdf').

Then, I want to go further and fill in 'simple.pdf's custom fields but I am getting the warning 'input PDF is not an acroform, so its fields were not filled'.. is it possible to preserve the 'acroform' attribute ?

Thanks !

Comment: How are you merging the 3 pdf templates? Please provide example code and/or files.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "acroform" attribute, like one single thing that would be maintained. It is much more complex than what you think (like for instance how would you handle two different PDFs with the same field names). You should check with pdftk and see if it even supports merging and retaining form fields. Many products do not.

Comment: And note, if it doesn;t support merging and retaining form fields then reverse your logic. Fill each form individually, flatten them and merge them after.